# Remove requirement for a click event from existing javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a modal popup that used to have a submit button.
As the content of the form is now pre filled, I want to remove the submit and have the form auto submitted.

The section of javascript that deals with this is below

```
afterShow: function () {
            $(document).on('submit', '#back-in-stock-popup-wrapper form[name="back_in_stock"]', function () {
                $.post('ajax/back_in_stock_subscribe_pop_up.php', $('#back-in-stock-popup-wrapper form[name="back_in_stock"]').serialize(), function (data) {
                    $('#contact_messages').html(data);
                    if ($('.messageStackSuccess').length) {
                        $('.back-in-stock-popup-wrapper-button-row').hide();
                        $('.back-in-stock-popup-content-wrapper').hide();
                    }
                });
                return false;
            });
        }
```

Instead of it waiting for a submit event, I want it to follow the code.

I'm hopeless with javascript and I thought I could just change it to

```
$(document)('#back-in-stock-popup-wrapper form[name="back_in_stock"]', function () {
```

but that didn't work.

How do I tell javascript to just proceed without waiting for the submit from the button click?

Comment: I have no clue what you expect that line of code to do.

Comment: Let me see if I can wrap my head around this terrible user experience you are suggesting. You're going to open a modal with a form in it, populate the form, and then auto submit it right in front of the users eyes. What's the point of that

Comment: this doesn't sound like you're trying to learn, it sounds like you're trying to avoid hiring a developer. you've basically answered every one of your own questions and avoided crediting anyone who has tried to help you. we're not a free code writing service.

Comment: @Iwrestledabearonce.Where have I answered every one of my own questions?

Comment: @gforce301 No, you assume too much. The form was to subscribe to notifications when a product comes back into stock. Given that the site only allows purchasing by registered and approved users, the name and email is already known, so pre populates the fields. Instead of presenting a user with a prefilled form and asking them to click submit, the popup will just advise that the request has been sent. They have to click a button to ask to be advised in the first place, so why make them click again to send something they didn't have to fill in. Actually makes the user experience better!

Comment: @StevePrice "I'm hopeless with javascript". You have no idea what you are talking about do you? That `afterShow` method is only going to happen once the modal is displayed on the screen. "I have a modal popup that used to have a submit button. As the content of the form is now pre filled, I want to remove the submit and have the form auto submitted." It will be a completely jarring, ugly and ridiculous user experience. Or it will be a pointless one. A modal open on the screen with a form displayed in it with nothing for the user to do and they're wondering why they are looking at it at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove the outer call like so:

```
afterShow: function () {
                $.post('ajax/back_in_stock_subscribe_pop_up.php', $('#back-in-stock-popup-wrapper form[name="back_in_stock"]').serialize(), function (data) {
                    $('#contact_messages').html(data);
                    if ($('.messageStackSuccess').length) {
                        $('.back-in-stock-popup-wrapper-button-row').hide();
                        $('.back-in-stock-popup-content-wrapper').hide();
                    }
                });
                return false;
        }
```

Comment: I don't know if this will be an issue in this situation, but in certain cases and depending on how you're populating the data into the fields, if you have to wait _at all_ for your data to be filled you may want to set an interval in order to check that the data is actually filled, otherwise you could end up with half-stuffed/empty form information.

Comment: @zfrisch A much better way than relying on timing functions would be using a callback or promise to ensure that this function only runs once the data-fill function runs. However I guessed that here, the data is already being filled in another function - but without more info, this is all just guesswork :)

Comment: Agreed! Personally I've had to use a timing function instead of Promises a handful of times but admittedly that was before they became so well supported. It's one of those things that kind of sticks with you as a possibility.

Comment: @General_Twyckenham Indeed, the form has already been filled, and validated.

Comment: @zfrisch We've all been there - urgh, just thinking about some of the code I've had to write in the past makes me sick lol

Comment: @StevePrice Cool - so try my suggestion out, feel free to accept/upvote if it helped, or update if you still have issues

Comment: @General_Twyckenham It doesn't give a success message, so it doesn't appear to be doing what's expected. I'll have to do some debugging on it.